# Code Igniter doesn't recognize my function in controller under a folder

Tags: codeigniter, controller, routes, subcontroller

I have a folder under my main controller-folder called admin, in that controller i have a file name admin.php which has a function xyz.

I want to access that function using this url

`http://localhost/webroot/admin/xyz`

However when I try to access it, it is giving me this error.

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

this is code of my routes.php file

```
$default_controller = "welcome";
$controller_exceptions = array('welcome','forum');
$route['default_controller'] = $default_controller;
$route["^((?!\b".implode('\b|\b', $controller_exceptions)."\b).*)$"] = $default_controller.'/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['admin'] = "admin/admin";
```

This is my .htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Also mod-rewrite is enabled :)

Please let me know why is it not working and how can i make it work. Any kind of help is really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your routes are stored in `application/config/routes.php` (not `router.php` as specified in your question). Try adding a route that uses a wildcard, like this:

```
$route['admin']        = "admin/admin";    //Routes to 'index()' function
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/admin/$1"; //Handles all other cases
```

`:any` will match a segment containing any character(s), after the *admin* segment, and will pass it/remmap it to the the *admin* controller.

The user guide contains more information on [controllers in sub-folders](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#subfolders) and [routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html).

Comment: Thank you Lefters for your quick response, but it has stopped even accessing

http://localhost/webroot/admin

give 404 error :S

PS: Yes its routes.php that was typo, sorry.

Comment: No problem. Can you access all of your other controllers? Have you tried setting your `RewriteBase` to: `RewriteBase /` or `RewriteBase /webroot/`?

Comment: Yes I can access my controller that is not in admin folder under main-controller folder.
I tried RewriteBase / and it leads me to localhost page, (i.e main page of wamp server)

RewriteBase /webroot and RewriteBase /webroot/ gives same error of 404. :(

Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you move the _admin_ controller to `application/controllers/` can you access it there? Is the controller itself defined properly - class name starts with an upper case letter, extends `CI_Controller` (or a class already extending that), etcetera?

Comment: What is that controller_exceptions supposed to be doing? Comment that out and use Lefters code for your admin and I'll take a bet it works. Or put the admin route at the top below the default controller.

Comment: OK It was working when I placed outside the controller folder.

Rick you are right, I have commented that thing already, and its giving some issues will post in a bit, thankyou.

Comment: I have removed those lines, it is working now, but the problem is that 

http://localhost/webroot/admin & http://localhost/webroot/

both redirect me to the main controller's index() function, which obviously it should not. however

http://localhost/webroot/admin/xyz leads me right to admin controller.
Here is my routes.php file

[code]

$default_controller = "welcome";
$route['default_controller'] = $default_controller;
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/admin/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';

[/code]

Comment: I added this to my routes.php and it works now, is it ok or should use some other way ? coz this three times admin seems to me like m enforcing it and not going by rule.

$route['admin'] = "admin/admin/admin";
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/admin/$1";

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Does your `index` function in _admin_ accept any parameters? If not, then you can route it like this: `$route['admin'] = "admin/admin/index";` Place this rule above: `route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/admin/$1";`

Comment: ok sounds great!! I'll use this $route['admin'] = "admin/admin/index"; as it doesn't take any parameters. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: No worries at all, I'm glad that I've helped! (`$route['admin'] = "admin/admin";` _might_ also work, as a slightly shorter alternative to `$route['admin'] = "admin/admin/index";`)

Comment: OMG!! :) no idea how but yes it does work now `$route['admin'] = "admin/admin"`!! Perfect :) Thanks